# some html element can't call by javascript when it were appended from any selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've created navigation within some peoples jquery plugin it is work as well when I echo my navigation from sever as html plane.
But when I used ajax to get all the menus data and append it to a selector I can't click to see menus drop down it seem the javascript to work with menus can't work when i used AppendTo method.

If i pass data to view from my main controller as html it will work as well.

```
class Main_Controller extends MY_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library("nav_libs");
        $this->data['menus'] = $this->nav_libs->navigation();
    }
}
```

Here is my method in my controller which I send it view as html type by ajax and append to a div

```
 public function navigation()
    {
        $this->load->Model('main/nav/nav_m'); 
        echo $menus = $this->nav_libs->navigation();
    }


<header class="cd-main-header">
    <ul class="cd-header-buttons">
        <li><a class="cd-nav-trigger" href="#"><span ></span></a></li>
    </ul>  
</header>
<nav id="nav_text">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                method:"GET",
                url:"main/new_navigation",
                dataType:"html",
                data:{},
                success:function(data, status){
                   var html =  $.parseHTML(data);
                    $('#nav_text').append(html)
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
<?PHP //echo $menus; ?>
</nav>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var MqL = 1170;
    moveNavigation();
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ? setTimeout(moveNavigation, 100) : window.requestAnimationFrame(moveNavigation);
    });

    $(document).on('click','.cd-nav-trigger', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        if ($('.cd-main-content').hasClass('nav-is-visible')) {
            closeNav();
            $('.cd-overlay').removeClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('nav-is-visible');
            $('.cd-primary-nav').addClass('nav-is-visible');
            $('.cd-main-header').addClass('nav-is-visible');
//            toggleSearch('close');
//            $('.cd-overlay').addClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
    $('.cd-search-trigger').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        toggleSearch();
        closeNav();
    });
    $('.cd-overlay').on('swiperight', function () {
        if ($('.cd-primary-nav').hasClass('nav-is-visible')) {
            closeNav();
            $('.cd-overlay').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
    $('.nav-on-left .cd-overlay').on('swipeleft', function () {
        if ($('.cd-primary-nav').hasClass('nav-is-visible')) {
            closeNav();
            $('.cd-overlay').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
    $('.cd-overlay').on('click', function () {
        closeNav();
        toggleSearch('close')
        $('.cd-overlay').removeClass('is-visible');
    });
    $('.cd-primary-nav').children('.has-children').children('a').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.has-children').children('a').on('click', function (event) {
        if (!checkWindowWidth())
            event.preventDefault();
        var selected = $(this);
        if (selected.next('ul').hasClass('is-hidden')) {
            selected.addClass('selected').next('ul').removeClass('is-hidden').end().parent('.has-children').parent('ul').addClass('moves-out');
            selected.parent('.has-children').siblings('.has-children').children('ul').addClass('is-hidden').end().children('a').removeClass('selected');
            $('.cd-overlay').addClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            selected.removeClass('selected').next('ul').addClass('is-hidden').end().parent('.has-children').parent('ul').removeClass('moves-out');
            $('.cd-overlay').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
        toggleSearch('close');
    });
    $('.go-back').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent('ul').addClass('is-hidden').parent('.has-children').parent('ul').removeClass('moves-out');
    });
    function closeNav() {
        $('.cd-nav-trigger').removeClass('nav-is-visible');
        $('.cd-main-header').removeClass('nav-is-visible');
        $('.cd-primary-nav').removeClass('nav-is-visible');
        $('.has-children ul').addClass('is-hidden');
        $('.has-children a').removeClass('selected');
        $('.moves-out').removeClass('moves-out');
        $('.cd-main-content').removeClass('nav-is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function () {
            $('body').removeClass('overflow-hidden');
        });
    } 
    function toggleSearch(type) {

        if (type == "close") {
            //close serach 
            $('.cd-search').removeClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-search-trigger').removeClass('search-is-visible');
            $('.cd-overlay').removeClass('search-is-visible');
        } else {
            //toggle search visibility
            $('.cd-search').toggleClass('is-visible');
            $('.cd-search-trigger').toggleClass('search-is-visible');
            $('.cd-overlay').toggleClass('search-is-visible');
            if ($(window).width() > MqL && $('.cd-search').hasClass('is-visible'))
                $('.cd-search').find('input[type="search"]').focus();
            ($('.cd-search').hasClass('is-visible')) ? $('.cd-overlay').addClass('is-visible') : $('.cd-overlay').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    }
    function checkWindowWidth() {
        var e = window,
                a = 'inner';
        if (!('innerWidth' in window)) {
            a = 'client';
            e = document.documentElement || document.body;
        }
        if (e[ a + 'Width' ] >= MqL) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function moveNavigation() {

        var navigation = $('.cd-nav');
        var desktop = checkWindowWidth();
        if (desktop) {
            navigation.detach();
            navigation.insertBefore('.cd-header-buttons');
        } else {
//            navigation.detach();
            navigation.insertAfter('.cd-main-content');
        }
    }
    $(".mclose").on('click', function () {
        closeNav();
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Can you try event delegation for dynamic html. New elements are not registered with first scan of DOM elements.

Comment: How about live(),On(),?

Comment: Yes that should ideally solve the problem

Comment: I've try but still can't

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or snippet.

Comment: Now I create already but not for ajax 
you can check it work as well 
https://jsfiddle.net/2eqf3cxa/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110704/discussion-between-heng-sopheak-and-deadlock).